# Diesel engine vs petrol engine characteristics

Tags: engine, diesel

Please explain why Diesel engines (in general):

- vibrate more.
- are louder.

I understand in principal how both engine types work so feel free to go into technical details. My assumption is that it probably has to do with the higher compression ratio of the Diesel engine.

Comment: Actually, after posting my answer, I see this is basically a dupe in every way except the vibration, and the vibration is directly linked to the same cause so I'll vote to close as dupe.

Comment: I agree. What's the usual course of action? Should I delete this question?

Comment: Hi lexeter, no reason to delete duplicates generally. They act as a stub redirecting to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right that the high compression ratio is the cause - you end up with a much greater pressure variation in the combustion chamber. See [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/12036/37) for explanation about the noise.

And the vibration is also directly related to this. With a bigger pressure differential, everything moves and vibrates more.